How to solve pagedown_chrome_print failed to generate output due to fail to open favicon.ico
I am a superfan of the use of pagedown::chrome_print("test.html") to convert my test.html to test.pdf. It worked 2 days ago. Today it did not, with the message:
Error in force(expr) : 
  Failed to generate output. Reason: Failed to open http://some numbers/favicon.ico # (HTTP status code: 404)

Apparently my chrome installation got updated today. That is the only difference I see.
Anyone else also having this problem? Anyone knows about a fix? The most recent mentions were some years back. Thank you!

Does putting a dummy favicon in  "test.html"s directory help?

I also noticed a lively discussion on this issue on github: https://github.com/rstudio/pagedown/issues/329

I just implemented the workaround suggested by @I_O in the comment in the servr package. You can install the new version via:
install.packages('servr')

Restart R, and pagedown::chrome_print() should work again.

It takes from www folder by default.
First create an www folder and after Put your favicon.ico into it.
Keep address as same like http://some numbers/favicon.ico
It will work, if it doesn't please comment back!

Thanks @Salierin, I did not try this. The workaround I_O suggested, works better for sharable R projects.
